# Custom view in nib instantiated as parent type

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uilabel

I've created a custom class inheriting from UILabel.  I placed a UILabel in my nib and set the class of the label to my custom class.  However, when the `viewDidLoad` method is called, the view is of the class `UILabel` instead of my custom class.

Any ideas?

Comment: which init methods did you override in your custom class?

Comment: I tried overriding both `drawRect` and `drawTextInRect`.  However, neither gets called at all, which led me to put a line in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` like this: `NSLog(@"label type: %@", [self.label class]);`, and the response is "label type: UILabel".

Comment: I think you need to implement initWithFrame:

Comment: yes, I did also implement `initWithFrame`.  I just forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create an instance of my CustomLabel in a test project. What I did differently was instead of dragging a UILabel, I pulled in an instance of CustomLabel into the view.

I implemented awakeFromNib against a target for the latest sdk as follows.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self class]]];
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect // called as expected
{
    NSLog(@"drawTextInRect: called");
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];
}
```

Couple of mysteries...
I implemented init and initWithFrame in CustomLabel, neither was called by the machinery that loads the view from the nib.